# Running Erdas command in MS-DOS

Tags: layers, erdas-imagine, stack

I have generated the following command line in ERDAS, and want to run it in MS-DOS. 
Getting an error- "***system cannot find the path specified"***.
I have checked the path by opening it in windows explorer, it navigates to the corresponding file,
have tried multiple options, by changing the location or going through .bat approach, still it won't work!

C:/ProgramFiles/Intergraph/ERDAS IMAGINE 2014/bin/x64URelease/modeler.exe
@"C:/Users/WRD/AppData/Local/Temp/ImagineCommandLine_modeler_3780003780"

Comment: Usually there is a blank between Program and Files too.

Comment: Well spotted.. it should (usually) be "c:\program files\Intergraph\ERDAS IMAGINE 2014\bin\x64URelease\modeler.exe" check the path and name of executable (should that be modeller.exe?) Blame MicroSoft, it could have just as easily been c:\programs\.. but they had to be all pedantic and make it \program files\ - they're responsible for soooo much pain!

Comment: You don't have to follow them: OSGEO4W installs in `C:\OSGEO4W\`, and my personal data is on D:\, not C:\user\somewhere\

Comment: I choose not to where ever possible. GDAL is in C:\GDAL_<version>, ArcGis is in C:\ArcGIS, Processing on D:\ (stripe RAID) and so is %temp% and %tmp%, personal and project data on E:\ (RAID 5)... but not every installer gives a choice. Program Files (x86) is even worse! Some data cannot have parentheses in the path name, you'd think they would have put a setting for program files and user files in the windows install somewhere!

Answer (score 1):

when using a path in command that contains a space you need to quote it:

"C:/ProgramFiles/Intergraph/ERDAS IMAGINE 2014/bin/x64URelease/modeler.exe" @"C:/Users/WRD/AppData/Local/Temp/ImagineCommandLine_modeler_3780003780"